# Gracefully terminate process inside of a QThread

Tags: python-3.x, qt, robotframework, python-multiprocessing, qthread

**TL;DR:**
When creating a process from main (imported from python package: multiprocessing), it is possible to terminate it and have a graceful exit, i.e. allowing the Robot script to Teardown. However, when creating a process inside a QThread the Robot script will halt at once without allowing for Teardown.

**Long story:**
I am trying to fix a hardware tester, the tester uses Python3 and QT for GUI and runs RobotFramework testscripts. To run the Robot tests a QThread is created to prevent the GUI from freezing, inside the QThread a process is started that runs the Robot Framework tests. When testing out a device that works, i.e. no failed tests, the Robot script runs through correctly. However, when I try to abort a test it is not allowed to gracefully shut down as it seems to be killed directly. Clearification: the Robot test exits but does not run the Teardown. If I instead create the process that runs the Robot test directly in "main" the program will exit gracefully when terminating it.

**My question is** how can I make the process inside the QThread behave the same way?

I have created a minimum example code to show what is happening. There are two files robotrunner.py and robottemplate.robot. If we set the test variable to 1 we will create the process directly inside main, and the program will exit gracefully after 2 seconds. If we set the test variable to 2 the process will be created inside a QThread and whilst terminating the test will be killed instantly (undesired).

[Running the test cases, nr1 is desired and nr2 is undesired behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJTFe.png)

robotrunner.py:

```
    import robot
import time
import time
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

class RobotExec(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.p = None

    #Run QThread
    def run(self):
        self.p = Process(target=startRobot)
        print("p.start()")
        self.p.start()

    def stop(self):
        print("p.terminate")
        self.p.terminate()
        print("Waiting to join")
        self.p.join()
        print("joined")

def startRobot():
    print("Robot run")
    robot.run('robottemplate.robot', loglevel='INFO')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test=2  #Choose between 1 and 2
    print(test)

    #nr1
    if test==1:
        p = Process(target=startRobot)
        print("p.start()")
        p.start()
        time.sleep(2)
        print("p.terminate")
        p.terminate()
        print("Waiting to join")
        p.join()
        print("joined")

    #nr2
    if test==2:
        robotExecutionThread = RobotExec()
        robotExecutionThread.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        robotExecutionThread.stop()
        time.sleep(6)
```

robottemplate.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup  Setup Sute
Suite Teardown  Teardown Suite

*** Variables ***

*** Keywords ***

wait for server
    [arguments]  ${host}  ${port}  ${timeout}=30
    wait until keyword succeeds  ${timeout} seconds  1 second  TCP server is alive  host=${host}  port=${port}

Setup Sute
    Log To Console    Setup Sute

Teardown Suite
    Log To Console    Teardown Suite
    Sleep    1s
    Log To Console    Tore down the suit

*** Test Cases ***
Test PC
    [Tags]    RevPC
    Log To Console    RevPC
    Sleep    1s

Test PC and PD
    [Tags]    RevPC    RevPD
    Log To Console    PC and PD
    Sleep    1s

Test PD
    [Tags]    RevPD
    Log To Console    RevPD
    Sleep    1s

Test PD and PE
    [Tags]    RevPD    RevPE
    Log To Console    PD and PE
    Sleep    1s

Test PE
    [Tags]    RevPE
    Log To Console    RevPE
    Sleep    1s

Test that should always run
    [Tags]    All
    Log To Console    This test should always run
```